# understanding do notation and bindings

Tags: haskell, monads, do-notation

I am very new to haskell and I am trying to understand the methodology used to create Monadic parser in this document https://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~gmh/pearl.pdf

Instead of following it exactly, I am trying to do it a little bit differently in order to understand it correctly, therefore, I ended up with this code

```
newtype Parser a = Parser (String -> Maybe (a, String))

item :: Parser Char
item = Parser (\cs -> case cs of
            "" -> Nothing
            (c:cs) -> Just (c, cs))

getParser (Parser x) = x

instance Monad Parser where
    return x = Parser (\cs -> Just (x,cs))
    (Parser p) >>= f  = Parser (\cs -> let result = p cs in
                  case result of
                    Nothing -> Nothing
                    Just (c,cs') -> getParser (f c) cs')

takeThreeDropSecond :: Parser (Char, Char)
takeThreeDropSecond = do
    c1 <- item
    item
    c2 <- item
    return (c1, c2)
```

This seems to be working, but I am having hard time following what is going on in do notation.

For example; in `c1 <- item`, what is assigned to `c1`? Is it the function that is contained in `Parser` type, or result of that computation, or what else? Moreover, second line in do notation is just `item`, so does it just run `item` but doesn't assign the result? And finally, what does `return (c1,c2)` produce? Is it `Parser (String -> Maybe ((c1, c2)), String)` or just `Just (c1, c2)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Parser` type wraps up a function that can 1) represent failure using `Maybe` and 2) returns the remaining text that was not parsed through `(a, String)` along with 3) some value `a` that was parsed, which can be anything.  The monad instance is the plumbing to tie them together.  The `return` implementation creates a `Parser` around a function that 1) succeeds with `Just` something, 2) does not modify its input text, and 3) directly passes the value given to it.  The `>>=` implementation takes a parser and a function, then returns a new parser created by first running the `p`, then based on whether that result passed or failed running `f`.

In `takeThreeDropSecond`, first `c1 <- item` says "parse the given using `item`, assign its result to `c1`, and feed the rest of the input forward".  This does not assign the function inside the `item` parser to `c1`, it assigns the result of running the function inside `item` against the current input.  Then you reach `item`, which parses a value using `item`, doesn't assign it to anything, and feeds the rest of the input forward.  Next you reach `c2 <- item`, which does basically the same thing as the first line, and finally `return (c1, c2)`, which would expand to `Parser (\cs -> Just ((c1, c2), cs))`.  This means that `return (c1, c2)` has the type `Parser (Char, Char)`.  With type annotations it would be

```
takeThreeDropSecond :: Parser (Char, Char)
takeThreeDropSecond = do
    (c1 :: Char) <- (item :: Parser Char)
    (item :: Parser Char)
    (c2 :: Char) <- (item :: Parser Char)
    (return (c1, c2) :: Parser (Char, Char))
```

Note that the last line of any monadic do block must have the same type as the function it is a member of.  Since `return (c1, c2)` has type `Parser (Char, Char)`, so must `takeThreeDropSecond`, and vice-versa.